# How can I get a value from the below string using the regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I need to grab a value "1" from below output using Python Regex:

```
SUCCESS
$<end>
$<SYS.Counter0.Increment>
$counter 0 incremented by 1
$SUCCESS
$<end>
```

Here, I need to grab a value "56" from below output using Python Regex:

```
$SUCCESS
$<end>
$<SYS.Counter0.State>
$value of counter 0: 56
$SUCCESS
$<end>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
txt1 = "SUCCESS $<end> $<SYS.Counter0.Increment> $counter 0 incremented by 1 $SUCCESS $<end>"
txt2 = "$SUCCESS $<end> $<SYS.Counter0.State> $value of counter 0: 56 $SUCCESS $<end>"

finder_digit = re.search("[1-9][0-9]*", txt2)

finder_digit = finder_digit.group(0)
print(finder_digit)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

s = """
$SUCCESS
$<end>
$<SYS.Counter0.State>
$value of counter 0: 562556
$SUCCESS
$<end>
"""

result = re.findall(r'\d+(?=\s\$SUCCESS)', s, re.MULTILINE)
print(result)
```